# MultipartForm Request: How to make the distinction between replace or delete file on server

Tags: rest, request, httprequest, endpoint, http-request-parameters

How can I make a distinction between replacing vs deleting a file on my server by a PUT request?

Lets say I have an endpoint for updating my user. A user can have a `picture` and a `backgroundPicture`. It also has simple fields like `age` or `username`.

The following could the user be requesting:

1. Update all fields (`picture` and `backgroundPicture` are set and getting replaced)
2. User only wants to update age (`picture` and `backgroundPicture` are set to `null`)
3. User wants to replace `backgroundPicture` but delete `picture` (`picture` is set to null)

How can my endpoint know if in (2.) the `picture` and `backgroundPicture` fields should be ignored instead of delete it?
Similar question goes for (3.): How can it know that the existing `picture` should be deleted.

#### Solutions which I thought about

- Add additional boolean flag param like `deletePicture` and `deleteBackgroundPicture`

  - **Cons**: Additional fields and feels misused
- Make a separate put/delete endpoint for files (e.g. [DELETE] `/users/{id}/picture`)

  - **Cons**: Updates are not atomic anymore and client requires two requests instead of one.

What is the best practice in these situations? I am sure, that I am not the first one with this issue :)

---

For those who can't imagine it programmatically:

```
data class UserDTO(
  val id: UUID,
  val username: String, 
  val age: Int, 
  @FormParam(FormParamKey.PICTURE) @PartType(MimeType.IMAGE_JPEG) val picture: File?,
  @FormParam(FormParamKey.BACKGROUND_PICTURE) @PartType(MimeType.IMAGE_JPEG) val backgroundPicture: File?
)
```

Lets say my endpoint looks like this

```
@PUT
@Path("/users/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
suspend fun putMultiPart(
    @RestPath id: UUID,
    userDTO: UserMultipartDTO,
    @Context httpRequest: HttpServerRequest
): Response { ... }
```